# Referencing images using SCSS

Tags: sass

I'm struggling to background images to load using SCSS.

Here's my config.rb:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Here's the SCSS extract:

```
.maincontent {
    background: image-url('mesh.png');
}
```

It's outputting the link address '`http://127.0.0.1/images/mesh.png?1364724560`' which isn't right. Yet the stylesheets, sass, and javascripts directories are linking just fine.

Comment: You're not telling us everything. Where could lght be coming from? Do you have some syntax error, another configuration file? Are you sure your config is even loaded?

Comment: Ignore the "lght" bit that was just my mistake when typing in my question. I've enabled 'relative_assets = true' but it doesn't have any effect. Perhaps my config file isn't being loaded. How do I test for that?

Comment: Change the folder names in the config, then you'll see if config is loaded.

Comment: Nope. I changed the directory in config.rb but it doesn't appear to be registering.

Comment: Nope what? Registering?

Comment: I meant nope config.rb wasn't being loaded for some reason. It's all working now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `relative_assets` to true in your config.rb.

[Compass Configuration Reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)

Comment: This was enabled a little further down in my config.rb